# memory issue with UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

I have UIViewController and I try load 10 UIWebView with youtube video on it. but my app use a lot of memory 100 MB when webviews is loading

here is my code.

`YouTubeView * youTubeView = [[YouTubeView alloc]`

```
initWithStringAsURL:subString
frame:CGRectMake(0, 5,
detailDescription.view.frame.size.width,
detailDescription.view.frame.size.height)];
[detailDescription.view addSubview:youTubeView];
[youTubeView release];
```

and youTubeView

```
      NSString *youTubeVideoHTML =
      [[NSString alloc]
       initWithFormat:@"<html><body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">
<div><object width=\"10\" height=\"90\"><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"  width=%f height=%f></embed></body></html>",



   @"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM",frame.size.width,frame.size.height];

// Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
// Load the html into the webview
[self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

what i am doing wrong ? or is there other way load uiviewbviews on UIViewController without commit 100MB memory.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are properly `release`ing your `youTubeVideoHTML` string after you are done with it.

Comment: thanks for replay i release youTubeVideoHTML after loadHTMLString call.

Comment: I think this issue has been here since iOS 7. The web views aren't releasing memory correctly I have heard from developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re creating the pages yourself, why not load all the YouTube videos into a single `UIWebView` one after the other, perhaps separated by `<p>` tags?

Comment: thanks for replay is this only one correct way? can I fix issue in my case?

Comment: i try load all youtube videos into a single uiwebview but again it use a lot of memory.

Comment: It is probably not the only way, and it sounds like it didn’t work for you anyway. I wonder if you are still holding on to more memory than you need? Is there a reason you are not using ARC for this project?